# Originally travelled as a tourist on B1/B2 visa. Can I use it for business purposes?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Earlier this year I applied for B2-TOURISM visa to travel to USA with my husband who was on a business trip. I got the visa stamped as B1/B2. However in DS 160 I specifically requested for tourism and medical purposes visa.

I travelled to USA on Feb 2015 and spent 16 days there. At the port of entry the officer marked B2 on top of the ink stamping.

Now that there is a business opportunity to travel to USA from my office in India. Since it's stamped as B1/B2 my visa cell executive suggests that I use my old visa. Also the visa is valid for 10 years and allows multiple entries. The entry is purely for gaining knowledge in a tool and attending knowledge sharing sessions.

My concerns are:

1. Visa officer marked B2 on the passport page on my first entry.
2. I requested B2-Tourism and medical treatment visa in my DS 160
3. The US consulate interviewer has not seen my itinerary and the POE personnel marked B2 with pen on the passport.

Comment: @JoErNanO: That question is about the opposite scenario.

Comment: @Flimzy You are right. Technically not a duplicate but same answer applies. Will retract my close vote as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Isn't B2 for tourism and B1 for business (meetings, etc)? If everything has been stamped/marked for the B2 side, then can she come in (to the US) using her visa if her intention is business?